# Python Chirp.io app not responding to "chirps"

Tags: python, chirp

I'm trying to build a chirp app that would just take a chirp and print the data. I'm running the python app in my terminal and am able to send/ emit a chirp but am not getting any indication that my app is receiving any data from test chirps from docs. I've debugged a little but my knowledge of python is limited but I have created a test .wav file from what the app captures, so I know its at least wired up to my microphone. Any ideas on how to get my app to respond to chirps?

Here's my code, I've borrowed heavily from the python sdk example file:

```
from chirp import ChirpConnect, CallbackSet, CHIRP_CONNECT_STATE
import argparse
import sys
import time

class MyCallbacks(CallbackSet):

    def on_state_changed(self, previous_state, current_state):
        """ Called when the SDK's state has changed """
        print("State changed from {} to {}".format(
            CHIRP_CONNECT_STATE.get(previous_state),
            CHIRP_CONNECT_STATE.get(current_state)))

    def on_sending(self, payload):
        """ Called when a chirp has started to be transmitted """
        print('Sending: ' + str(payload))

    def on_sent(self, payload):
        """ Called when the entire chirp has been sent """
        print('Sent data')

    def on_receiving(self):
        """ Called when a chirp frontdoor is detected """
        print('Receiving data')

    def on_received_verbose(self, payload):
        """
        Called when an entire chirp has been received.
        Note: A length of 0 indicates a failed decode.
        """
        if len(payload) == 0:
            print('Decode failed!')
        else:
            print('Received:' + str(payload))

    def on_received(self, payload):
        print(list(payload))



app_key="REDACTED"
app_secret="REDACTED"
input_device=0
output_device=1
# Initialise ConnectSDK

sdk = ChirpConnect(app_key, app_secret, debug=True)

sdk.audio.wav_filename = './test.wav'

print(str(sdk))
print(sdk.audio.query_devices())

# Configure audio
sdk.audio.input_device = input_device
sdk.audio.output_device = output_device
"""     sdk.audio.block_size = block_size
    sdk.sample_rate = sample_rate """

# Set callback functions
sdk.set_callbacks(MyCallbacks())

# Generate random payload and send
payload = sdk.random_payload()
sdk.start(send=True, receive=True)
sdk.send(payload)

try:
    # Process audio streams
         while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            sys.stdout.write('.')
            sys.stdout.flush()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Exiting')

sdk.stop()
sdk.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
Chirp Connect 3.3.0 [3.1.8 052] initialised.
> 0 Built-in Microphone, Core Audio (2 in, 0 out)
< 1 Built-in Output, Core Audio (0 in, 2 out)
State changed from Stopped to Running
......................................
```

Comment: Could you post the output of the two print statements there?

Comment: @joerobot edited the post to show the output, thanks for checking out the Q!

Comment: Everything is looking ok there. One thing to note is that the callback function names are important, so your verbose one will not get called. Do you get any audio data in test.wav?

Comment: @joerobot Yeah, I got audio back in the test.wav and ty for the callback functions names heads up! Could it be how i'm running it? Im just running the app through the terminal on my MacBook. Goal is to use the code on a raspberry pi to trip a relay on successful chirp reception.

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but did you ever figure out what the problem was?  I have a similar issue.